# Magento 2.3.2: Cannot install on Xampp

Tags: magento2.3.2, localhost, exception-error

I have tried installing Magento 2.3.2 with sample data on localhost(xampp) but not successful. In the exception log, I'm getting the below thing:

```
[2019-09-02 08:10:27] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentosample.core_config_data' doesn't exist
```

Could anyone please help me on how to rectify this error?

Comment: upgrade the setup version : php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: @SavanPatel, I have ran upgrade command and gets the same error.

Comment: something wrong during m2 installation, try to export core_config_data table with data from another fresh m2 setup.

Comment: @AnasMansuri, I have uninstall the magento and tried installing again but still the error.

Comment: could you please create new database, may be core_config_data.frm exist in xampp/mysql/bin/data/

Comment: Just to check you are aware m2 is not supported with windows? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: @DominicXigen, Thanks. However, I have tried installing Magento 2.3.2 without sample data and it works. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

you cant install magento using the commande bin/magento setup:upgrade

please follow dev doc guide if you want to use CLI installer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html

or browser wizard https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html

I suggest the latter it shows you if your environment is fit to install Magento (readiness check at first step)

after that you run `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy` in root folder in order to install sample data